# xUnit.Net Ignore Exceptions when debugging a test in test runner

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, xunit.net

In Visual Studio, I usually keep the default settings for handling exceptions, which stops the debugger on an exception that isn't handled in user code.

In [XUnit.net](https://github.com/xunit/xunit%22XUnit.net%22), I use `Assert.Throws<T>` for exception testing:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException(() => { TestMethod(); });

static void TestMethod() {
    if (condition)
        throw new ArgumentException("Test Message");
    /// .. more code here
}
```

Works great when I *run* it from a test runner (ReSharper or NCrunch).

When I *Debug* from either of these environments though, I get stopped in the debugger with `An exception of type ... occurred in ... but was not handled in user code`.

Is there a clean way to make that message go away only when I'm debugging a unit test?

I could set the Debugger Options in Visual Studio to ignore those errors, but that's not an idea I like much.

I could roll my own try/catch block but that seems to be like reinventing a bad copy of xunit.  Looking at the source, I can see that the code *is* in a try/catch block, but it's apparently not 'user' code as far as Visual Studio is concerned (cause it's in the DLL).

I can't be the first guy to run into this, but haven't seen it discussed here so I must be making a newbie mistake.  Is there a good solution out there?

Comment: You can register the xUnit `AssertException` type as an individual switchable exception in the list but as you allude to, this 'feels wrong' to you. The bottom line though is that stopping on all thrown exceptions does just that - there is no 'just my' exceptions. If this was possible, how would you propose to debug the exception management ? If you're getting hit with too many 'irrelevant exceptions' when debugging, is there a reason you cant use Traits and/or filteri1ng to the test you want to debug to prevent such 'false positives' ?